# Should I use past simple or past perfect

Tags: past-tense, aspect, perfect-aspect

> Before I made a second order that did well, I had thought my first
>   order had not gone through.But when I received the confirmation for
>   both orders, I knew the first order had also succeeded. I realised I
>   had ordered the item twice.

Shall I say *had succeeded* or *succeeded?*

I would choose *had succeeded* because the first order succeeded first and I knew this only after I received the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, had succeeded is the better option. Because the action of success happened before I received confirmation.

We use Past Perfect tense when something occurs **before** a specific time in the past.